# Which of the two sentences is grammatically correct ?4

Tags: grammar

The constitution of our country has provided complete freedom for followers of all faiths to practice their religion. We are fully satisfied with and strongly deny the possibility of any change in them.

The constitution of our country has provided complete freedom **to the** followers of all faiths to practice their **religions**. We are fully satisfied with **it** and strongly deny the possibility of any change in **it.**

Answer (score 1):

Neither is fully correct.

1. *For* is correct in the first, since the subject of an infinitive clause is marked by *for*, not *to*. The definite article is not needed, but not ungrammatical either, though it sounds more idiomatic without it.
2. *Religion(s)* is grammatical in both the singular and the plural, but the singular would be more common.
3. Both instances of *it* in the second version make more sense than *them* in the first, though both are equally grammatical. If you use *them*, you're saying that you are perfectly happy with the followers of various religions (or, if you use *religions* in the plural in #2 above, the religions themselves) and don't want to change these people/religions. If you use *it*, you are happy with your constitution and the constitution is what you don't wish to change. Whether you repeat the *it* is a matter of style; personally, I probably wouldn't, but there's nothing wrong with either (though I would repeat the subject as well if you repeat the object).
4. *Change(s) in it* is not incorrect or ungrammatical as such, but *change(s) to it* is more idiomatic. Additionally the constitution (presumably) still provides this freedom, and there doesn't seem to be any reason to focus on this as a result of a preceding action, so the simple present works better in the first sentence.

So I would suggest the following version:

> The constitution of our country provides complete freedom for followers of all faiths to practice their religion. We are fully satisfied with it, and we strongly deny the possibility of any changes to it.